# .net 5 logging to azure app service protocol stream not working outside startup.cs

Tags: c#, logging, azure-web-app-service, .net-5, blazor-server-side

i currently have a very basic .NET 5 Blazor Server App running at my azure app service.

Deployment works as expected, app is running and i can call my service properly. Now i tried to add logging to azure stream and it worked sometimes, now not anymore for a not known reason. Following is happening in error state:

I have configured logging within Program.cs in CreateHostBuilder

```
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                {
                    logging.ClearProviders();
                    //logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics(); //<== NEVER EVER add this again in .net core as it is implicit called and will cause missing logs!!!: https://wakeupandcode.com/logging-in-asp-net-core/
                    logging.AddConsole();
                    logging.AddDebug();
                })

            .ConfigureServices(serviceCollection => serviceCollection
                .Configure<AzureFileLoggerOptions>(options =>
                {
                    options.FileName = $"{DateTime.UtcNow.Hour.ToString()}_{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}_diagnostics_";
                    options.FileSizeLimit = 50 * 1024;
                    options.RetainedFileCountLimit = 5;
                }))

            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

As you may see i commented AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics out as it is implicit called from framework when deployed to azure, so there is no need to call it explicitly! AND I had this issue short time before, and when i commented it out logging worked fine again, so i thought this was the problem... it was not!

Now problem occured again, so more details:

I use this configured logging first in startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILogger<Startup> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            this._logger.LogPrettyInformation($"Current Environment is: {env.EnvironmentName}");

            if (env.IsDevelopment() || env.IsStaging())
            {
                string envi =  env.IsDevelopment() ? EnvironmentEnum.Development.ToString() : EnvironmentEnum.Staging.ToString();
                this._logger.LogPrettyInformation($"Met condition for: {envi}");

                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else if (env.EnvironmentName.Equals(EnvironmentEnum.Debug.ToString()))
            {
                this._logger.LogPrettyInformation($"Met condition for: {EnvironmentEnum.Debug.ToString()}");
                
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else if (env.IsProduction())
            {
                this._logger.LogPrettyInformation($"Met condition for: {EnvironmentEnum.Production.ToString()}");

                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");

                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }     

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            });
        }
```

These lines with all that LogPretty-stuff are all working just fine! I can see them at my local debbuging output AND at azure protocol stream too! Looks good ha?

Now I use DI to log from pages and services and stuff, this is the part that is not working any more, but worked from time to time. Now when i call my Counter page as brought up to me by the VS template (WeatherForecastService is the same issue...) I have some logs after i increase the count. But they are only shown in Debug output in my Visual Studio debugging session, NOT in my azure stream.

Any Ideas? In short:

- all logs working fine in debug session (output window)
- logs from startup working fine in debug and in azure stream and of course in filesystem under application as configured
- others not! Not in file and not in stream, just in debug output!

Method for logging - LogPretty - is not throwing any exception.

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your usage of logging in Startup.cs and program.cs is all good.

```
logging.AddDebug();
```

It gives the debug logging in local. Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0) for logging .net 5 application

I am following the below steps to get the log stream information

**Enable the `filesystem logs` on Azure Portal**

To enable the logs, In **Azure portal** go to **App service** -> **App Service Logs**.

Enable the ***Application Logging (Filesystem)***. Then put the *Verbose* level to be sure to not miss any log.
[image]

**Write the configuration code**

Use the package `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices`

Then, add the following code while you configure your web host:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args) => CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
    {
        logging.ClearProviders();
        // We have to be precise on the logging levels
        logging.AddConsole();
        logging.AddDebug();
        logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics(); // which is not required
    })
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.Configure<AzureFileLoggerOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.FileName = "my-azure-diagnostics-";
            options.FileSizeLimit = 50 * 1024;
            options.RetainedFileCountLimit = 5;
        });
    })
    .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

Use below lines of code in a controller or anywhere else, acquire the logger via IoC and start the logging.

```
private ILogger Logger { get; }
public AwesomeController(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    this.Logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("AwesomeLogger");
}

[HttpGet]
public void Get()
{
    this.Logger.Debug("DEBUG message. GET enpoint was called.");
    this.Logger.Error("Error message. Something went wrong !");
}
```

Check the logs via Log Stream (In azure portal go to **App Service** -> **Log Stream**)

Refer [here](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-configure-azure-web-app-logging-with-net-5-786918eb2ff3)

Comment: Under which section I can see the same in App Service > Monitoring > Logs?

Comment: yes, you can see all type of telemetry information in **App Service -> Monitoring -> Logs**